# Android / Java - Overriding

Tags: java, android, oop, overriding

I have two Classes "BaseActivity" and "ChildActivity" i.e. ChildActivity inherts BaseActivity. 
**Question: In my following Code Snippet, whenever i press LEFT BUTTON - it logs me "I am From Child Activity". What would i need to do if i want to call SUPER CLASS functionality by default.**

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    };

    protected void configureTitleBar(String title) {
        ImageButton imgLeftButton = ((ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.actionBarLeftButton));
        imgLeftButton.setOnClickListener(BaseActivity.this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId() == R.id.actionBarLeftButton){
            printCustomLog("I am From Base");
        }
    }
}
```

Child Activity:

```
public class ChildActivity extends BaseActivity implements OnClickListener{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_child);

        configureTitleBar("MyTitle");
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(v.getId() == R.id.actionBarLeftButton){
            printCustomLog("I am From Child Activity");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get super class functionality, you can

**a)** Not Override the `onClick()` method at all (but I don't think that's what you want)
**b)** Call `super.onClick(v)` from `onClick()` in your child class.

The code in your `ChildActivity` will then be.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // Check some condition if you want to handle it in Child class
    if(condition){
        printCustomLog("I am From Child Activity");
    }
    // Else, as default, call Base class's onClick()
    else{
        super.onClick(v);
    }
}
```

Comment: Damn! how i forgot super.onClick(v) :-/ Thanks A.Fatir.

Comment: @nalaiqChughtai Pls mark as the answer if it helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.actionBarLeftButton) {
            // here's my work
        }
        super.onClick(v); // it will call Super's OnClick
    }
```